# How can I add a document Property that is able to contain a List?(Spotfire 7.0),

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I want to set a document property with a list I have from my IronPython code. But I do not a see a "List" type available when adding a new Document Property.
The only close to list is type String
[Example of a DXP that has what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS10Z.png)

But I am not able to edit that property to check how it was added.

Answer (score 2):

in your example DXP, this is just a string with comma separated values.

to do this in your Python code:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
delimiter = ","
Document.Properties["MyProp"] = delimiter.join(my_list)

print Document.Property("MyProp")
>>> 'a,b,c'
```

later, when you need to iterate on the value, you can convert it back to a list easily:

```
my_prop = Document.Properties["MyProp"]
delimiter = ","

my_list = my_prop.split()

print my_list
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

---

one final note: if your list contains integers or anything other than strings, you'll need to join it a little differently since Python is picky about types:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
delimiter = ","

Document.Properties["MyProp"] = delimiter.join(str(i) for i in my_list)

print Document.Property("MyProp")
>>> '1, 2, 3'
```

you can convert it back to an integer list with `int()`:

```
my_prop = Document.Properties["MyProp"]
delimiter = ","

my_list = [int(i) for i in my_prop.split()]

print my_list
>>> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Ok thank you for that Information. I am going to test and let you know how it goes